# WP Появление красного прямоугольника на определенных страницах, с чем связано?

Tags: php, wordpress, отладка

Помогите, кто сталкивался, попалась такая проблема что на странице категории WP при начальной загрузке начал появляться красный прямоугольник в пунктирной зеленой рамке...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём ни каждый раз, обычно только пока страница не попала в кеш, но это очень бросается в глаза. Проблема появляется не каждый раз, а только если перезагружать Chrome страницу через `Ctrl+R` Отладка через консоль, или добавлением в параметры `wp-config.php`  не помогло.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

Ошибка выпадает и на локальной версии сайта, что отметает проблему на сервере. Может кто что-то посоветовать ? Появляется, только на этой странице.

[site:https://bahisyasal.net/genel/](http://site:https://bahisyasal.net/genel/)

Comment: а что в отладчике? может, это криво отображается какой-то элемент разметки, типа прелоадера?

Comment: Нету прелоадеров... и только на этой странице почему-то. На 1сек появляется, а потом исчезает

Comment: Я и тротлинг включал, и скорость загрузки уменьшал, что бы как-то отследить рендеринг DOM дерева... не помогло, не могу поймать этот элемент

Comment: Там с выдачи надо... оно через site: только попасть можно... то защита от Турецкого надзора.